# Retrieve all feature IDs displayed on the viewport into JSON using Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, extents, json

I have build a map application using leaflet, where I display a WMS layer from Geoserver. What I am trying to do now is to get all the elements which are currently on the Bounding Box and store them in a JSON.
I have read [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62067/how-to-apply-bounding-box-filter-in-leaflet-wms), that leaflet applies a BB on the fly according to the position of the viewport. But what I don't know is how I can export the fid's of the elements into a JSON or array etc. 
Ideally I want to be able onbutton click to get the JSON with all the features displayed in the viewport.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WMS cannot handle properties of the features displayed in a bbox (it can only fetch properties of a feature given a point, read the docs for WMS's `getFeatureInfo`).

What you *might* want to do is using a different approach, like doing a [WFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Feature_Service) request to geoserver, which will return the geometries and properties of all features inside a bounding box.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of the WFS option, although I only know how to do it using Openlayers and its strategies (BBox etc.). It will make my application quite heavy if I load all these features at once and then on panning I send requests to the server. That's why I was looking for an alternative and the URL I provided thought it refers explicitly to WMS.

Comment: You can try other approaches, such a server-side script which can query the DB and return the properties of features in a bbox. Or a server-side query to the WFS and filter only certain properties of the features.